# How to move PDF files depending on number at beginning of file name into directory starting with same number?

Tags: cmd

I try to move PDF files. An example is the file `12345  234456.pdf` with two spaces in file name into folder `12345-customername`.

I have tried this:

```
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=E:\customer files\"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims= " %a IN ('dir /b /a-d "* *.pdf" ') DO (MOVE "E:\customer files\%a  %b" "E:\customer files\%a\") 
GOTO :EOF
```

The problem is that the source directory only matches the first 5 numbers of the destination folder, not the full name of the folder, and the command fails.

So I would like to know:

Can the destination be a wildcard that would match just the first 5 numbers of the source file?

I have a PDF file `12345  345678.pdf`. I want to move it into an existing directory `12345-random customer`. The source PDF file can stay with the same name once moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you need a batch file like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceFolder=E:\customer files"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D-H /B "%SourceFolder%\* *.pdf" 2^>nul') do call :MoveFile "%SourceFolder%\%%I"
endlocal
goto :EOF

:MoveFile
for /F "eol=| tokens=1 delims= " %%J in ("%~n1") do set "TargetFolder=%~dp1%%J"
for /D %%J in ("%TargetFolder%*") do move /Y %1 "%%J\" & goto :EOF
md "%TargetFolder%"
if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF
move /Y %1 "%TargetFolder%\"
goto :EOF
```

The first **FOR** executes in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in background the command line

```
dir /A-D-H /B "E:\customer files\* *.pdf" 2>nul
```

The command **DIR** lists to **STDOUT** of separate command process

- the file names of all **non-hidden files** in specified directory `E:\customer files` because of `/A-D-H`
- in bare format with just file name and file extension because of `/B`
- matching the wildcard pattern `* *.pdf`.

**DIR** outputs an error message to **STDERR** redirected with `2>nul` to device **NUL** to suppress it if no directory entry is found matching these requirements.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures everything output to **STDOUT** of separate command process and process the captured text line by line.

Empty lines are ignored by **FOR** which do not occur here except no matching file name was found by **DIR**.

**FOR** ignores by default on using `/F` all lines starting with a semicolon. A file name can start with `;` and therefore `eol=|` is used to redefine the end of line character to a vertical bar which a file name cannot contain.

**FOR** splits up a line by default into substrings (tokens) using space/tab as delimiters and assigns just first space/tab delimited string to specified loop variable `I`. This line splitting behavior is disabled by `delims=` which defines an empty list of delimiters.

So the entire file name is assigned to loop variable `I` which is concatenated with source folder path to a full qualified file name and passed to subroutine `MoveFile`.

The first **FOR** in subroutine `MoveFile` processes the file name **string** without path and file extension referenced with `%~n1` and splits it up on spaces. The first space delimited string is assigned to specified loop variable `J` which is concatenated with drive and path of source file referenced with `%~dp1` ending always with a backslash to an environment variable `TargetFolder`.

The second **FOR** in subroutine `MoveFile` searches for a non-hidden directory starting with the first space separated string of current file name, i.e. starting with the number at beginning of the PDF file names. If a directory matching this simple wildcard pattern is found in the source folder, its full qualified name is assigned to loop variable `J` and command **MOVE** is executed to move the PDF file into this folder. Then the **FOR** loop and the subroutine `MoveFile` is exited and batch file execution continues on first **FOR** command line at top of the file.

Otherwise there is no subdirectory in source directory for the current file. So the batch file creates this directory. If that fails for some reasons, the subroutine is exited without moving the current file. Otherwise the file is moved into just created directory.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of operator `&` and [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)

Comment: and created new folders/directories as well..such a perfect solution. brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the full name of the folder with a `for /d` loop.

(untested):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=E:\customer files\"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims= " %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "* *.pdf" ') DO (
  for /d  %%c in ("%%a*") do (
    MOVE "E:\customer files\%%a  %%b" "E:\customer files\%%c\"
  )
) 
GOTO :EOF
```

Note: if you have more than one folder starting with the same 5 digits, it will try to move the file to each of them (and will work only for the first one (not available any more after the first `move`))

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a modern-day version of Windows, PowerShell can be used. When you are satisfied that the files will be moved correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` cmdlet.

=== Move-CustomerFiles.ps1

```
$sourcedir = 'C:\src\t\custfilesmove\customer files'
$destdir = 'C:\src\t\custfilesmove\customer'

Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourcedir -Filter '*.pdf' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $d = $_.Name -replace '(\d+) .*', '$1'
        $targetdir = [Io.Path]::Combine($destdir, $d)
        if (-not (Test-Path $targetdir)) { mkdir $targetdir | Out-Null }
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $targetdir -WhatIf
    }
```

Then, invoke it from a cmd.exe shell with:

```
powershell -NoProfile -File .\Move-CustomerFiles.ps1
```